# How to change the type of an existing entity in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a web app built with Spring Boot and JPA and I would like to change the type of an entity already persisted inside the database. 
Let me explain it better through an example.

I have an entity Person

```
@Entity
public class Person{
     @Id
     private Long personId;
     private String name;
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
     private List<Car> cars;
     ...
}

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

this Person may have one or more cars, which are represented by the entity type Car:

```
@Entity
public class Car{
     @Id
     private Long carId;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
     private Person owner;

}

@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {}
```

and an Employee classe which inherits from Person:

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends Person{
     private String employeeId;
     ...
}

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

Let's say we persist an entity of type Person inside the database. After a couple of months this Person becomes an Employee so we have to change the type of this entity, already persisted inside the database, from Person to Employer, without losing any information (included the list of cars he may have).

Is there a correct way to do so?

Comment: yes. this may just be the most simple way to express the problem. and is not the question.

Comment: The key design principle of JPA is that you interact with the data layer of your app just like with regular Java objects. Can you change the type of a regular Java object? Well, there's your answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, your application supports the upgrade of a `Person` to `Employee` and you want the record already existing in the database to be used and updated with the new attributes (e.g. `employeeId`).

I think this is a problem of [Inheritance strategy](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/). You have two classes : `Person` and `Employee`, with `Employee` a subclass of `Person`. You need to decide what tables would be used to store the records corresponding to `Employee` and `Person` objetcs.

If you opt for a distinct table for each entity class, then you have to handle manually the *upgrade* of a `Person` to `Employee` (that is you remove the record in one table and add it to the other).
However, if you choose to store both entities in a single table, then you may use the same record. See "Single Table" section in [the document](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/).

For this to work, you also need to make sure the unique id is the same between the classes `Person` and `Employee` (e.g. `personId`). Otherwise, you will still have two distinct records (within the same table).

On the other hand, as I mentioned in the beginning, any inheritance strategy would work, as long as you accept to remove the `Person` entity and create the *new* `Employee` entity upon *upgrade*. This remove / create often has a complexity depending on existing relationships and integrity constraints.

Comment: Can I remove a person without automatically lose the relationships (the list of cars for examples)?

Comment: I assume cars have no reason to exist without the Person. In such case, if you configure your integrity constraints so that your DB is normalized, either the cars will be deleted automatically or you will have to delete them (manually) before deleting Person. If you are actually able to delete Person and keep the "orphan" records of cars, it means your integrity constraints are poorly configured, which is error prone, in addition to leaving your database with orphan records (that use space without being useful).